# log4net with AsyncCallback C# socket client

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, log4net

I'm making an Async Socket Client of C#.

The client is almost the same with link example from Microsoft :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-client-socket-example

I also use log4net for logging, with this config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <log4net>
        <root>
            <level value="ALL" />
            <appender-ref ref="console" />
            <appender-ref ref="file" />
        </root>
        <appender name="console" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%date %level %logger - %message%newline" />
            </layout>
        </appender>
        <appender name="file" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
            <file value=".\log\logfile.log" />
            <appendToFile value="true" />
            <rollingStyle value="Size" />
            <maxSizeRollBackups value="5" />
            <maximumFileSize value="2MB" />
            <staticLogFileName value="true" />
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline" />
            </layout>
        </appender>
    </log4net>
</configuration>
```

In short, the config above make the log go to the file specified and showing it to GUI using DoAppend.

Then, in the Connect and Receive callback from Socket.
I called the log.Info, log.Error and etc.

In the DoAppend :

```
this.sideLogText.Text += loggingEvent.Level.Name + ' ' + loggingEvent.MessageObject.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
```

It is to filled the GUI text box.
But I got error, 'The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.'

So, I used this:

```
 this.Dispatcher.Invoke(
                DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)(() =>
                {
                   ...write to GUI
                }
            ));
```

No error, but the text is not come out on GUI.
I'm confused.
Am I missing something here ?

Answer (score 0):

try changing the dispatcherpriority from Normal to ContextIdle

Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { }), DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle);

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatcherpriority?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2